# Android Snackbar showing white background behind text

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-snackbar

I am using android design support library `Snackbar` using following code.

```
    Snackbar.make(rootView, "Sample Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("OK", view -> {})
            .setDuration(Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .show();
```

On Android 4.4 I am getting it like this:

[image]

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.

## EDIT

`.setAction("OK", view -> {})` contains a lambda expression in the 2nd parameter. its just a empty listener.

Comment: If you add the code of the `view` you are adding for your action, it would be easier to find an answer for you.

Comment: not sure what you are asking for. thats all the code that for snackbar. I am not using any custom view

Comment: what is your `rootView`??

Comment: @Boss, `rootView` is the root view of the activity, it is a RelativeLayout.

Comment: I think you should pass a `CoordinatorLayout` to the SnackBar

Comment: @Boss is that mandatory?

Comment: I am not sure. But thats how I use it. Didn't thought about using another parent view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88348/discussion-between-g-revolution-and-boss).

Comment: It may be just a glitch that you're noticing on an emulator... Did you try it on a real device?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem using FrameLayout as root view on a real device (android 6.0) when showing the snackbar inside a dialog. After changing it to

```
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

the problem went away and the snackbar is showing correctly.